# Galaxy grand prime - App.onCreate() called too often?

Tags: android

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enable "Don't keep Activities" developer option
2. Start any app, press Home Button - all activities are destroyed
3. Tap app's icon - App resumes and its Application.onCreate() method is called.

It looks like App exits every time all of its Activities are destroyed, even though the App shows in the list of recent processes.

Is this a bug?

**EDIT**: I rebooted the device and now it behaves normally. Other things that were wrong before reboot: some installed apps icons didn't show on desktop and some app names were wrong.

Android version: 5.1.1
Kernel 3.14.27-1070395
Build LMY48B.G531FXXU1APG2

Comment: Recent's list does not mean running apps

Answer (score 3):

That is happening because you are specifically telling android to not keep your activity in memory when it is no longer visible.  That is the entire point of this option

> Enable "Don't keep Activities" developer option

It is there to test things like simulating your app being killed by the OS because it is low on memory. If you disable this developer option, things will return to normal.